# PHP - actually execute value of variable

Tags: php

I have an array of fractions:

```
$fractions = array('1/8', '1/4', '1/2');
```

Is there any way that I can get PHP to actually perform the division to get a decimal value?

Something like:

```
foreach($fractions as $value) {
    $decimal = [the result of 1 divided by 8, or whatever the current fraction is in value];
}
```

Comment: You can construct your array much better, but if you won't - as AJ said, use `eval()`

Comment: The array was simply to help illustrate the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you have it, you should just explode and do your division:

```
foreach($fractions as $value) {
    $exp = explode('/',$value);
    $decimal =  $exp[0] /  $exp[1];
}
```

You could also eval(), but I usually try not to do that. It is a performance hit as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can call [`eval()`](https://www.php.net/eval):

```
$fractions = array('1/8', '1/4', '1/2');

foreach($fractions as $value) {
    $decimal = eval("return $value;");
    echo "$value = $decimal\n";
}
```

Comment: For this to work the line must read `$decimal = eval("return $value;");` or the eval will fail with `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end`. I don't really like using `eval` either

Comment: Thanks for the additional suggestion AJ. I will keep eval in mind for possible future use.